# OptionsDialog / OptionsPropertyGrid

Tags: c#

Do you know how to set property(if exist) to display all numeric value from object in hex format.
I use this code :

```
  OptionsDialog options = new OptionsDialog();
  options.OptionsPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = myobject //<--this object contains numeric value
```

Now on my object editor I can modify value but are display in decimal format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a converter:

```
public class IntToHexTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            return string.Format("0x{0:X8}", value);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            string input = (string)value;

            if (input.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                input = input.Substring(2);
            }

            return int.Parse(input, NumberStyles.HexNumber, culture);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Define a class for data to be associated with the PropertyGrid:

```
[DefaultPropertyAttribute("Name")]
public class Data 

public UInt32 stat;
[CategoryAttribute("Main Scanner"), DescriptionAttribute("Status"), TypeConverter(typeof(IntToHexTypeConverter ))]
public UInt32 Status
{
    get { return stat; }
}
```

Reference data for propertyGrid. (here, myData is a Data).

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myData;
```

Source: http://koniosis.blogspot.nl/2009/02/integers-as-hex-in-propertygrid-c-net.html

Comment: You have provided converter code, but it isn't obvious (at least to me) how you use it in this case.

Comment: See the example link: http://koniosis.blogspot.nl/2009/02/integers-as-hex-in-propertygrid-c-net.html or http://www.emoticode.net/c-sharp/propertygrid-values-in-hexhexadecimal-using-class-derived-from-typeconverter.html

Comment: What if that link goes dead? That is the key reason SO discourages link only answers. If there is something in those links that completes this answer then include it in your answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with the complete example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use string.Format(), you can specify how a numeric value should be displayed.

```
int i = 42;
string s = string.Format("Display as integer: {0}, or as hex: 0x{0:X}", i);

Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
```